# React Native: Dynamic Bottom-Sheet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, bottom-sheet

Hello I want to build a FlatList with several items and each of them should open a bottom-sheet. To realize this I want to do it dynamic. But I get an error.

`` TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating `_this[_reactNativeRawBottomSheet.default + index]= _ref2`) ``

```
import RBSheet from "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet";


function Test({ navigation }) {
  const index = 0;
  return (
    <View style={styles.containerMain}>

      <View>
        <Button
          title={`OPEN BOTTOM SHEET ${index}`}
          onPress={() => this[RBSheet + index].open()}
        />
        <RBSheet
          ref={(ref) => {
            this[RBSheet + index] = ref;
          }}
        >
          <Text>I am {index}</Text>
          <Button title="close" onPress={() => this[RBSheet + index].close()} />
        </RBSheet>
      </View>

    </View>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: please add to your code how you integrate between `Test` component and `FlatList`

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because `this` only can be used in class components, your code is a functional component.

If you want to use the same approach, you can use the class to render the component:

```
import RBSheet from 'react-native-raw-bottom-sheet';
import {View, Button, Text} from 'react-native';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    const index = 0;

    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Button
            title={`OPEN BOTTOM SHEET ${index}`}
            onPress={() => this[RBSheet + index].open()}
          />
          <RBSheet
            ref={(ref) => {
              this[RBSheet + index] = ref;
            }}>
            <Text>I am {index}</Text>
            <Button
              title="close"
              onPress={() => this[RBSheet + index].close()}
            />
          </RBSheet>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```